# How do I evaluate template expressions in my Ansible plugins?

Tags: ansible

I just wrote a small Ansible lookup plugin for fetching passwords from `pass`. I've set this variable in `group_vars/all.yml`:

```
pass_store: "{{ inventory_dir }}/passwords"
```

Inside my plugin I fetch this variable and pass it to `os.environ["PASSWORD_STORE_DIR"]`.

The problem is that the value hasn't been evaluated. The literal value of the variable is used, not the evaluated value.

For example:

```
os.environ["PASSWORD_STORE_DIR"] = variables["pass_store"]
```

I now expect the environment variable `PASSWORD_STORE_DIR` to contain:

```
/home/tomas/my-project/passwords
```

Instead it contains:

```
{{ inventory_dir }}/passwords
```

Does the Ansible API provide some way of evaluating variables containing template expressions like this?

Comment: Whomever close-flagged the question, can you please specify what part of my question was unclear? I'm basically looking for a function from the Ansible API that lets me evaluate template expressions like `"{{ my_var }}"`.

Comment: @techraf I assumed your comment was a joke about Ansible being a tool for building worlds. What does my question have to do about writing? Ansible is a deployment tool for programmers. Also, your close-flag said my question was unclear, not that it belongs on a different site.

Comment: No, the reason I voted for closing is: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: @techraf I'm not asking for debugging help. I'm clearly saying what the problem is (the variable hasn't been evaluated) and I'm asking whether the Ansible API provides a way of evaluating variables from within plugins. If you think that's unclear from the question, I welcome you to edit it. I'm not the most literate person on this site.

Comment: Then we have a disagreement. If four more people think like me, the question will get closed, if not - then it will stand as is.

Comment: @techraf I edited my question to try and make it more clear. If you think it's better, please remove your flag and comments. I don't imagine my question having 0 votes and being flagged will positively affect my chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I don't understand your fixation on the words: "clear" and "unclear". I voted for closing with the reason the question does not contain the code. You are not asking a question "how things work?" you are stating "I wrote some code, I wanted it to work like this, but it doesn't". The question in its current form has, imho, no value for the community.

Comment: @techraf The text you highlighted from the close reason only applies to questions seeking debugging help, i.e. "why isn't this code working". I have no idea why you're applying it to my question. I'm asking a direct, easily understandable question that anybody with Ansible plugin development experience should be able to answer. There's no point in including the code of my plugin, it would only be in the way. I wouldn't usually argue about it but I'm worried your close flag will hurt my chances of getting an answer.

Comment: And I hope the question will get closed (for "why?" - read above).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
os.environ["PASSWORD_STORE_DIR"] = self._templar.template(variables["pass_store"])
```

This will evaluate the variable content and replace Jinja tokens by appropriate values.